# Apache SSL error trying to use pg_query_params()

Tags: php, postgresql, ssl

I sometimes get an obscure error from Apache when trying to make requests to my remote PostgreSQL 9.3 database using `pg_query_params()` in PHP 5.3.29:

```
<br /> <b>Warning</b>: pg_query_params() [<a href='function.pg-query-params'>function.pg-query-params</a>]: Query failed: SSL error: block type is not 01 in <b>/index.php</b> on line <b>171</b><br />
```

It only happens intermittently—the query usually succeeds—so I know it's not a syntax or other problem with my code. However, for the sake of completeness, here's the relevant PHP and SQL:

```
...
$query = <<<POWER_TEACHERS
WITH teachers AS (
    SELECT ca.started_by_id, sus.email, sus.zip_code
    FROM   common_activityinstance ca, socrative_users_socrativeuser sus
    WHERE  ca.end_time >= $1::date
    AND    ca.end_time <  $2::date + 1
    AND    ca.started_by_id = sus.id
    AND    sus.zip_code IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ca.started_by_id, sus.email, sus.zip_code
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
    ORDER BY random()
    LIMIT 250
), activities AS (
    SELECT ca.id, t.email, t.zip_code
    FROM   common_activityinstance ca, teachers t
    WHERE  ca.end_time >= $1::date
    AND    ca.end_time <  $2::date + 1
    AND    ca.started_by_id = t.started_by_id
)
SELECT zip_code, email
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.user_uuid) s.user_uuid, a.id, a.email, a.zip_code
    FROM   students_studentresponse s, activities a
    WHERE  s.activity_instance_id = a.id
    ORDER BY s.user_uuid
) sub
GROUP BY email, zip_code
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
ORDER BY zip_code;
POWER_TEACHERS;
$result = pg_query_params($con, $query, array($lastWeek, $today)); // error here
...
```

What could be causing this strange behavior?

Comment: That's a network transport issue of some kind. Are both client and server vaguely recent? Are they connected via an unreliable link perhaps? Is there some kind of network proxy in use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the client and server being "recent", but I can successfully make other queries via `pg_query_params()` immediately before and after the above query fails (the link between client/server is reliable enough, and there is no proxy in use). The only difference I can see is that my successful queries directly reference the `$_POST` global variable, whereas this one doesn't. Could that possibly matter? (I'm grasping for straws because this is extremely bizarre.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else, I "solved" this problem by ditching PHP,  switching to Node.js, and using the excellent [pg-native](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-native) module. My query from above, totally unchanged, executes with no problem whatsoever.